# How to open a symlink without the terminal window popping up?

Tags: macos, terminal, symlink, nohup

How can I open a symlink without the terminal window popping up? Moreover, when I close the terminal window, the application quits as well. I tried using

```
nohup open symlink1
```

without any results. I have made a symlink to the iTunes executable (the one inside the contents package, NOT the iTunes.app) which I want to be able to open by double clicking the link, but without the terminal window popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out a solution:

Make an executable (intended as the link)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS
nohup ./iTunesX &
exit
```

and change under preferences in Terminal

> When the shell quits: close if the shell exited cleanly

Change iTunesX and the cd path to any desired target.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make an HFS+ alias?  Command-option-drag the iTunes app anywhere you want on your machine, and it should work like you want it to.

Comment: same result, the terminal popping up. Like I said, I want to link to a an EXECUTABLE within the itunes.app package (/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunesX), NOT the itunes.app itself.

Comment: @mewoshh, but you didn't explain why.  Double-clicking an alias to the app folder most definitely does not make terminal start.  Since that was your stated goal, I thought I would provide you with a working solution.

Comment: To clarify - I do not wish to link to the itunes.app FOLDER but to an executable INSIDE the contents folder.